# How to map number ranges to numbers in SQL Server or Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a calculation in my query which results into float numbers.

What I should do is to map each range of [x-0.005,x+0.005) to x.

 For example:

| shown number | lower bound | upper bound |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.12 | 0.115 | 0.125 |
| 0.17 | 0.165 | 0.175 |
| 0.18 | 0.175 | 0.185 |

These ranges are a lot so CASE/WHEN wouldn't work. So, are there any other options to solve this?

Comment: I think you would need to provide some example data and desired results, especially as 12.5 and 13.5 are not 0.xx

Comment: You are right, sorry for my messed-up question. I corrected the numbers and added a table @Stu

Comment: According to your requirement what does 0.125 should be mapped to: 0.12 or 0.13? Because it is in 0.005 distance to both.

Comment: So your "shown number" is just your (lower bound + upper bound) / 2... - is that the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @astentx great question, made another edit! the upper bound would not be taken

Comment: Looks like you need simple mathematical rounding: `round(some_value, 2)`

Comment: @Stu nice point. but how can I dynamically determine the bounds with the selected values. Imagine I have 0.184, how can it determine the upper and the lower by itself? :P

Comment: @PanizAsghari you haven't provided actual sample data and actual expected results so I'm not sure exactly what your question is.

Comment: [`round`](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/rounding-functions/amp/) in clickhouse, [`round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in T-SQL

Comment: @astentx it perfectly works in sql server but clickhouse rounds 0.125 to 12. I want it to be 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
WITH
    0.005 AS step,    
    (
        SELECT groupArray(ranges)
        FROM 
        (
            /* Emulate the Ranges-table. */
            SELECT arrayJoin([(0.115, 0.125), (0.165, 0.175), (0.175, 0.185)]) AS ranges
        )
    ) AS ranges
SELECT
    x,
    arrayFirst(range -> x >= range.1 - step AND x < range.2 + step, ranges) AS range
FROM 
(
    /* Emulate the test table. */
    SELECT arrayJoin([0.12, 0.17, 0.18, 0.99]) AS x
)

/*
┌────x─┬─range─────────┐
│ 0.12 │ (0.115,0.125) │
│ 0.17 │ (0.165,0.175) │
│ 0.18 │ (0.175,0.185) │
│ 0.99 │ (0,0)         │
└──────┴───────────────┘
*/
```

Take into account that the comparison of float numbers is *approximate*.

Answer (score 0):

For example data it will do

```
Select lower_bound, upper_bound, (lower_bound + upper_bound)/2 shown_number
from mytable
```

Comment: I think lower and upper bounds are what the OP is looking for.

Comment: The title says to map number ranges to numbers, not vice-versa, it's totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

A solution :

```
SELECT FLOOR(N*200 -1)/200, N, CEILING(N * 200 + 1)/200
FROM   T
```